# Get Current Identity through Linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Person { 
int Id{get;set;}
string Name{get;set;}
}
```

and set Id as Itentity Feed

```
ARMSEntity _entities=new ARMSEntity();

_entities.AddObject('Person',obj);
```

Now I want to get the current Id that is inserted into the database.

Thanks for any help in Advance

Comment: Thew new `ID` is available only after the row has been **saved**, e.g. after you call `.SaveChanges()`

Comment: Sir I am using this with transaction scope .on the basis of this PeronId I have to store the data into the Child Table .So if Any Error occurs i want to rollback the whole transaction.

Comment: That doesn't change anything - the `ID` value is **NOT** available until after the row has been stored in the database. And it can still be rolled back if it's inside a transaction ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using (var context = new MyContext()) {  
context.MyEntities.AddObject(myNewObject);  
context.SaveChanges();
```

When u Find Identity Seed Value try..

```
int id = myNewObject.Id; }
```

Comment: Sir I am using this with transaction scope .on the basis of this PeronId I have to store the data into the Child Table .So if Any Error occurs i want to rollback the whole transaction.

Comment: Here Everything is going on Context and when u  find Identity Seed Value its avaliable  only when u commit Entity Context(or by savechanges).

n yaa if u want Rollback your data then use TransactioScope in Code get value by procedure through
**ScopeIdentity()** function

Comment: I have Already used this process but the value committed by stored procedure is not rollback .